# How to debug zombies on device without active session with xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, event-handling, nszombie

I'm debugging an overuse of released objects using NSZombieEnabled. It's OK if you have an active connection with mac and are running from xcode4. But I'm hunting one bug that occurs after long run and I would like to test in on device without the connection. Just wondering is it possible to have some code for catching an event when a message is sent to zombie and then, ten display some NSLog with relevant information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open up "Organizer" and view the console output. You get the same data that you would from the Console when debugging while attached to the Mac.

Window -> Organizer -> Click the arrow next to your device and select "Console"